# Clips + Java integration acquire string and put response

Tags: java, multithreading, integration, clips

I have a problem with the integration of clips in Java.
My clips project is structurad in a series of question and answer. Now i want to integrate in java.
This is my java

```
    import net.sf.clipsrules.jni.Environment;

public class Example {

    public static Environment clips = new Environment();
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        clips.load("myclips.clp");
        clips.reset();
        clips.run();
    }
}
```

and this is my clp

```
(defrule starting-rule
 (declare (salience ?*highest-priority*) (auto-focus TRUE))
  => 
 (printout t "***Start***" crlf)
 (focus PROFILE)
 (set-strategy random))

(defrule PROFILO::ask-car 
 (not (question (name car) (questiona ?) (risposta ?)))
 =>
 (bind ?response (yes-or-no "You have a car? "))
 (assert (question (name car) (domanda "L'auto e' tua? ") (risposta ?risposta)))
 )

....
```

This is the output in java console

```
***Start***
You have a car? (yes/y/no/n):
```

Now the console wait an answer in console, and until i don't answer i can't exit from the clips.run() method, but i want to take question and put in an interface and let that an user answer to it.
How i can do this? I have to use thread? how?

Answer (score 0):

There are four examples included with CLIPSJNI, http://www.clipsrules.net/?q=Downloads/CLIPSJNI, that demonstrate how to wrap an interface around a CLIPS program.